# DB Design: Subscription / Invoice Model

Tags: database, database-design, stripe-payments, payment, subscription

So I've been tasked with redesigning the database for one of our existing apps (to normalise and restructure some of the more gigantic tables) and I'm struggling to come up with a solid design for handling payments to our service.

**Background Info**

Our service offers various plans (Personal, Family, Business etc.) that all come with Monthly & Yearly subscription options.

We use Stripe as our payment gateway for Personal and Small sized business users but also offer an option to pay by invoice for our larger clients. Which I feel is where a lot of the complexity lies, in trying to combine the two.

For every subscription, we generate a license-key provided to each User attached to a specific account (that had a subscription purchased for them). So for every subscription, I'm attaching a license key to it.

**End Goal**

I ideally would like to be able to track all the payments and subscriptions from both payment funnels (Stripe & Manual Invoices) and to manage recurring payments (renewing subscriptions, cancelling overdue subscriptions, changing subscription plans, trials, discounts etc).

**What I have so far**

[image: ERD Initial Design]

My Design definitely has a long way to go for sure as it way too complex (probably more than it needs to be).

But the idea behind it all was to track all payments made (both Stripe & Invoice) then link those payments to a subscription (and a license).

Any help would be appreciated on this! :)

Comment: And the question is...?  What issue do you foresee here?  What should we help with?  Quickly looking, I noticed that Purchases has a FK to Plan, yet no link in the diagram.

Comment: Every subscription should result in one or more invoices. Some invoices might be paid by using Stripe. Some might be paid by credit card. (An invoice is not a payment or a type of payment. An invoice is a request for payment.)

Comment: Stripe's API & dashboard allows you to "pay" an invoice in Stripe "out of band" (outside of Stripe). Perhaps doing so would allow you to keep the info all in one data model (Stripe's) while not always having payments occur in Stripe itself? https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/overview#paid